# mysql query to mock revision number

Tags: mysql

I have a table looking like this

```
+-----------+---------+-------+------------------------+-----------------------+
| commentID | reftype | refID |        comment         |       timestamp       |
+-----------+---------+-------+------------------------+-----------------------+
|         1 | A       |   123 | Comment 1              | 2015-11-19 09:05:18   |
|         1 | A       |   123 | Comment 1, First edit  | 2015-11-19 09:06:18   |
|         2 | A       |   123 | Comment 2              | 2015-11-19 09:05:44   |
|         1 | A       |   123 | Comment 1, Second edit | 2015-11-19 10:05:23   |
+-----------+---------+-------+------------------------+-----------------------+
```

My goal is to select the latest edit of each comment and add a revision number column. So my desired result would look like this

```
+-----------+---------+-------+------------------------+---------------------+-----+
| commentID | reftype | refID |        comment         |      timestamp      | rev |
+-----------+---------+-------+------------------------+---------------------+-----+
|         1 | A       |   123 | Comment 1, Second edit | 2015-11-19 10:05:23 |   3 |
|         2 | A       |   123 | Comment 2              | 2015-11-19 09:05:44 |   1 |
+-----------+---------+-------+------------------------+---------------------+-----+
```

Using the following query I get pretty close but **how do I get get my revision column**? Is it possible with my approach or do I need to change it completely?

```
SELECT c1.* 
FROM comments c1
LEFT JOIN comments c2 ON ( c1.commentID = c2.commentID AND c1.timestamp < c2.timestamp ) 
WHERE c2.timestamp IS NULL 
AND c1.referencetype = 'A'
AND c1.referencekey = 123
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Above query gives me

```
+-----------+---------+-------+------------------------+---------------------+
| commentID | reftype | refID |        comment         |      timestamp      |
+-----------+---------+-------+------------------------+---------------------+
|         1 | A       |   123 | Comment 1, Second edit | 2015-11-19 10:05:23 |
|         2 | A       |   123 | Comment 2              | 2015-11-19 09:05:44 |
+-----------+---------+-------+------------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the latest revision date *and* the count in a single aggregation subquery:

```
SELECT c1.*, c2.numcomments as rev
FROM comments c1  JOIN
     (SELECT c2.commentId, COUNT(*) as numcomments,
             MAX(timestamp) as maxtx
      FROM comments
      WHERE c2.referencetype = 'A' AND c2.referencekey = 123
      GROUP BY c2.commentId
     ) c2
     ON c1.commentId = c2.commentId
ORDER BY timestamp DESC ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T1.*,T2.`rev`
    FROM
        table_name T1 
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT T.`commentID`,T.`reftype`,MAX(T.`timestamp`) AS timestamp,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE table_name.`commentID` = T.`commentID` AND table_name.`reftype` = T.`reftype`) AS rev FROM table_name T GROUP BY T.'reftype',T.`commentID`) T2 
    ON
    T2.`commentID` = T1.`commentID` AND T2.`reftype` = T1.`reftype` AND T1.`timestamp`= T2.`timestamp`
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get it. How do I get revision numbers from this?